# Swift: Split comma-separated strings, but not if comma enclosed in single quotes

Tags: swift, xml, string

My XML file encodes strings in between single-quotes. Array elements are comma-separated.

> 'Hello', 'World'

Normally, extracting comma-separated values is easy:

```
let result = myString.split{ $0 == "," }.map(String.init)
```

The problem is that I can't recklessly split on the comma: if the comma is enclosed in single quotes it is *text*, otherwise it is an array element separator:

> 'Hello', 'World', 'Hello, World'

Should produce:

```
["Hello", "World", "Hello, World"]
```

Note two things:

1. An empty single quotes is an empty string that can't be discarded (it's an element in an array)
2. I can't guarantee whitespace between the elements; a user may have tampered with a file.

> 'Hello', 'World'     , 'Hello, World', ''

should produce:

```
["Hello", "World", "Hello, World", ""]
```

I need some way to differentiate between a comma-separated value which lies outside of the single quotes: ', ' A better approach would probably be to retain anything in between single-quotes, but I don't know how to do this.

Comment: This looks more like a CSV format. – Are strings always enclosed in single-quotes? Can there be a single-quote inside a string? How would that be escaped?

Comment: Yes, strings are always inside single quotes. The user can't use them. Odd, I know; this is from a niche program from I believe around 2003.

Comment: @MH175 Can you elaborate more on what this format is? `XML` doesn't have native "arrays"

Comment: I'm afraid I can't :-( Yeah, it's a totally unique product from the early 2000s that ran on its own hardware. The encoding is not quite XML, but very close. If you looked at it quickly you would easily be fooled into thinking it is!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about separating the string by single quotes and removing elements containing a single comma and a space afterwards?

Note that you should remove the first/last element of the result, since the input starts and ends with a single quote and that produces an empty element after separating.

```
var result = myString.components(separatedBy: "'").filter { 
    $0.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces) != ","
}

result.removeLast()
result.removeFirst()
```

Comment: Thanks I updated my answer. One problem with this is it filters empty strings

Comment: Closer-- the problem is the whitespace; sorry I'm trying to figure out how to write whitespace in Stackoverflow

Comment: @MH175 Can an element contain a single comma and nothing else? If not, my updated answer should work.

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you for the edits and help. How did you get Stackoverflow to keep your whitespace?

Comment: @MH175 You welcome! I entered `&nbsp;` several times.