# C#: Split comma-separated strings, but not if comma enclosed in single quotes

Tags: c#, string

I am parsing a text file from some old hardware and I need to extract an array of strings from one long string.

- Elements are comma-separated
- Each individual string is enclosed in single quotes

> 'Hello', 'World'

```
{"'Hello', "'World'"}
```

Single quotes for any other reason are illegal and there is no escaping character equivalent; you cannot write the word "Bob's" nor can do something like "Bob\'s".

Ordinarily it would be easy to get the individual elements by splitting on the comma:

```
string testString = "'Hello', 'World'";
ArrayList result = new ArrayList(testString.Split(',');
```

But I can't do this; if a comma is in-between single quotes it is *text*, not a separator.

This is one element:

> 'Hello, World'

```
{"'Hello, World'"}
```

How can I extract the elements checking to see if the comma is in-between single quotes?

> 'Hello', 'World', 'Hello, World'

```
{"'Hello'", "'World'", "'Hello, World'"}
```

One more detail: I cannot guarantee the amount of whitespace between elements:

> 'Hello',     'World',  'Hello, World'

P.S. Here is the same question I asked for Swift: [Swift: Split comma-separated strings, but not if comma enclosed in single quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47660214/split-comma-separated-strings-but-only-if-not-enclosed-in-single-quotes/47660728?noredirect=1#comment82281388_47660728)

Comment: Have you considered using a RegEx?

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I'm just not good at it.

Comment: Split it using `'''` instead, then the tokens you get will be alternating between text enclosed by '' and separator in between (consisting on commas and whitespace)

Comment: @MH175, just do the filtering, the actual tokens will be at alternating index, starting from 1 I believe as the 0th position should be unrelated text before the first '.

Comment: @MH175, I just read the question in your Swift link, the idea is similar to his whereby you tokenize by single quote, then remove tokens consists of a single comma with whitespaces.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry I'm very rusty on C#. How can I remove the comma elements regardless of the amount of whitespace surrounding them?

Comment: @MH175 Is there any chance that element will contain a single quote? how would the single quote be escaped inside an element? e.g. `'I don\'t know'`.

Comment: It sounds like you should be using an [actual CSV parser](http://ctl-global.github.io/data.html).

Comment: `string.Replace()` comes to mind first then `string.Split()` which can all be done in a single line

Answer (score 2):

You have not answered whether the strings can contain embedded single quotes & how they might be escaped.

If every string follows the pattern of `[SingleQuote][Text][SingleQuote]`, here's a RegEx that will do what you need:

`'[^']+'`

If you have empty strings in the single quotes, use:

`'[^']*'`

Comment: Thanks this works! It would be nice if you could show the complete code.

Comment: Actually I see a problem with this: it gives the wrong result on the empty string

Comment: What do you get with an empty string?

Comment: I get a plain comma ', '.

Comment: Test with 'Hello', 'World', 'Hello World', '', ''

Comment: Didn't think you would have empty strings. Replace the + with *

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be using `Json` deserialzer  :

```
    private string[] F(string input){    
        return Newtonsoft.Json.
           JsonConvert.DeserializeObject("["+input+"]",typeof(string[]));
       }
// now call F:
var result= F("'Hello','World','Hello,World'");
```

Comment: So many opportunities for this to fail with some bad character.

Answer (score -2):

I tried this approach but I wonder if this works most of the time.

```
        const string str = "'Hello', 'World', 'Hello, World'";
        ArrayList arrStr = new ArrayList(str.Split('\''));
        List<string> myString = new List<string>();
        for (int i = 0 + 1; i < arrStr.Count; i+=2)
        {
            myString.Add(arrStr[i].ToString());
        }
```

Also, i'm not sure if your string has contractions in it.